# Recursive BubbleSort giving wrong output

Tags: c, recursion, bubble-sort

I am trying to implement recursive bubblesort for array of structures. But, it is giving wrong output when I sort the array by Employee name. I am not able to figure out what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// GLOBAL VARIABLES
char *stringDataType = "string";
char *integerDataType = "integer";

// Employee structure
struct Employee
{
    char *name;
    int age;
};

// Method to swap two structures by reference.
void Swap(struct Employee *first, struct Employee *second)
{
    struct Employee temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}

// Method to check if the first string is greater than second string or not
// 1 if the first string is greater
// -1 if the seond string is greater
// 0  if both the strings are equal
int IsGreaterThan(char **first , char **second)
{
    int index = 0;
    while(*((*first)+index) == *((*second)+index))
    {
        index++;
    }

    if(*((*first)+index) > *((*second)+index))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(*((*first)+index) < *((*second)+index))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Method to check if the first structure is greater than second structure or not
// 1 if the first structure is greater
// -1 if the seond structure is greater
// 0  if both the structure are equal
int IsStructGreaterThan(struct Employee *first, struct Employee *second)
{
    int index = 0;

    return IsGreaterThan(&(*first).name, &(*second).name);
}

// Bubble Sort Method
void BubbleSort(struct Employee array[], int size, char *dataType, int swapped)
{
    int i;

    if(swapped == 0 || size == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        swapped = 0;

        if(dataType==stringDataType && (IsStructGreaterThan(&array[i], &array[i+1]) == 1) || dataType==integerDataType && array[i].age > array[i+1].age)
        {
            Swap(&array[i], &array[i + 1]);
            swapped = 1;
        }
    }

    BubbleSort(array, size-1, dataType, swapped);
}

// Entry point of the program
int main()
{
    struct Employee array[] = {{"John", 45}, {"Mary", 23}, {"Celina", 79}, {"Mike", 41}};
    int arraySize = 4;
    int index;

    printf("Before Sorting : \n");
    for(index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    {
        printf("(%s, %d) ", array[index].name, array[index].age);
    }

        printf("\n");

    int swapped = 1;

    BubbleSort(array, arraySize, stringDataType, swapped);
    printf("After Sorting by name : \n");
    for(index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    {
        printf("(%s, %d) ", array[index].name, array[index].age);
    }

        printf("\n");

    BubbleSort(array, arraySize, integerDataType, swapped);
    printf("After Sorting by age : \n");
    for(index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    {
        printf("(%s, %d) ", array[index].name, array[index].age);
    }   

    printf("\n");       
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Before Sorting :                                                              
(John, 45) (Mary, 23) (Celina, 79) (Mike, 41)                                 
After Sorting by name :                                                       
(John, 45) (Celina, 79) (Mary, 23) (Mike, 41)                                 
After Sorting by age :                                                        
(Mary, 23) (Mike, 41) (John, 45) (Celina, 79)
```

Comment: Check what would happen to your `IsGreaterThan` function if names are equal (not an unlikely scenario in real implementations!)

Comment: Aside from the string comparison issue (which is numerous on this site), your algorithm is wrong. For a proper bubble-sort, any single *sweep* that results in `swapped == 0` should terminate the entire sort. You reset `swapped = 0;` before each *comparison*. That is wrong; it doesn't belong in your for-loop. It should be *after* the quick-exit if it was zero coming in to the function, but  *before* the for-loop.

Comment: There's certainly a fatal bug in the comparison. If the two strings are equal then following the loop, `index` will be referring to after the end of the strings & the final comparison will be of characters not in the strings. However that isn't your bug because you're not sorting duplicates.

Comment: I did not see @WhozCraig answer before I wrote my answer. he is totally right. it is the only logic mistake you did. you can totally comment out swapped, or move swapped=0 out of for loop

Comment: @Adem it isn't the only logical mistake. No sorting takes place *at all* if the type passed is not `stringDataType`, even after properly fixing the string comparison logic.

Comment: @WhozCraig, but I tried. when I comment out, it works fine. stringDataType is provided well, isnt it ? it is defined as global. so you can check it with ==

Comment: @WhozCraig, sorry I did not realize. it does not work for ages

Comment: I'm betting the assignment is looking for [**something like this**](http://ideone.com/6MkiX2). You may want to look at it for a minute or two.

Comment: @WhozCraig it is much more better. why you dont write this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `swapped = 0` before the for-loop, not inside it, and fix the string comparison as per other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Strings should be compared by `strcmp()` instead of comparison operators.

You could change `IsStructGreaterThan()` into

```
int IsStructGreaterThan(struct Employee *first, struct Employee *second)
{
    return strcmp(first->name, second->name);
}
```

Comment: @timraru it is not working. First name is not sorted other that it is working. `(John, 45) (Celina, 79) (Mary, 23) (Mike, 41)` this is the output as per your answer.

Comment: the string comparison in the OP is buggy, but there are more errors.